# Secure individual passwords in password manager with U2F?

Tags: password-management, u2f

Given that U2F as implemented for instance by the YubiKey is stateless I am wondering if any password manager supports encrypting each individual password stored in a password collection using U2F.

This would help against the common problem that opening the password manager is already a large security risk (think CTRL+A, CTRL+C to copy all entries) and prevent giving away your complete passwords just because an attacker recorded one challenge/response communication for a single key.

Background:

- U2F is not an encryption standard, but a authentication standard and uses public/private keys for authentication of server challenges.
- Based on its use of public/private key signatures though it should be possible for a password manager to keep "handles" for each stored password, which after being signed by the U2F device yield the actual encryption key.
- See here for a potential use of u2f for [simple text encryption](https://github.com/sebflipper/u2f-node-text-encryption). I don't think it the right way to use the handle as a salt, but the general idea is there.

Answer (score 1):

U2F can't be used to encrypt anything.
U2F devices can be asked only two things :

- Enroll a new identity (Create a new key pair)
- Authenticate using an existing Identity. (Sign the hashed server challenge with few other info)

So I don't think your question makes sens, but perhaps you can give more details.

Comment: U2F devices can only sign things, really (Yubikey does not even store any secret). But isn't a signature enough to turn a stored sequence of bytes into a potential encryption key?

Comment: @ChristopherOezbek It's poor form at best to use non-random key sources, and a security hole that you might not see at worst. I strongly advise you don't do it, or ask on https://crypto.stackexchange.com where you might get a better answer.

Comment: @JeffFerland At the moment my password manager does not even encrypt each individual password, but just everything together. So I am looking for anything that might help me go above static password to open my password vault.

Comment: Use a hardware device that can support asymmetric encryption (OpenPGP card, Yubikey 4, etc.) and encrypt each password individually. The Yubikey 4 can require physically touching the device to perform decryption, and OpenPGP cards can be put inside external card readers.

Comment: by the way, I don't understand what you are trying to achieve by that... It doesn't protect against phishing, it doesn't protect against local attacks... just saying...